# Why Redefine Function Namespace?

Tags: c++, linker, namespaces

Compiling and executing the following files works without any issues. When I remove the `aos::` from in front of the `euler` function in *Ode.cpp* the compiler throws the following error.

```
Ode.cpp:13: undefined reference to `aos::euler(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >* (*)(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, unsigned int, unsigned int), std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >*, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why does it do that? I already defined the `namespace` in both the definition and the implementation files of Ode.

Cheers,
MrMcKizzle

### Ode.hpp

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifndef ODE_HPP
#define ODE_HPP


namespace aos 
{ 
    std::vector< double > * euler(
        std::vector< double > * (*)(std::vector< double > *, Uint32, Uint32),
        std::vector< double > * x, Uint32 dt, Uint32 t
    );

    class Integrator {
        public:
            Integrator();
            //~Integrator();
            std::vector< double > * (*integrator)(
                std::vector< double > * (*)(std::vector< double > *, Uint32, Uint32),
                std::vector< double > * x, Uint32 dt, Uint32 t) = euler;  ///< Stores a pointer to the default ODE integrator function (defaults to euler)   
            std::vector< double > * integrate(
                std::vector< double > * (*)(std::vector< double > *, Uint32, Uint32),
                std::vector< double > * x, Uint32 dt, Uint32 t
            );
    };
}
#endif
```

### Ode.cpp

```
using namespace aos;

std::vector< double > * aos::euler(
    std::vector< double > * (*f)(std::vector< double > *, Uint32, Uint32),
    std::vector< double > * x, Uint32 dt, Uint32 t)
{ 
    std::cout << "aos::euler" << std::endl;
    return f(x, dt, t);
}

Integrator::Integrator(){}

std::vector< double > * Integrator::integrate(
    std::vector< double > * (*f)(std::vector< double > *, Uint32, Uint32),
    std::vector< double > * x, Uint32 dt, Uint32 t)
{
    std::cout << "Integrator::integrate" << std::endl;
    return this->integrator(f, x, dt, t);
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "Ode.hpp"

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::vector< double > * dummysys(std::vector< double > * x, Uint32 dt, Uint32 t)
{
    cout << "main.cpp::dummysys" << endl;

    return new vector< double >();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    aos::Integrator * intgr = new aos::Integrator();

    vector< double > x;
    //integrate(dummysys, &x, 16, 123);
    intgr->integrate(dummysys, & x, 16, 123);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, the Ode.hpp is the same as Ode.cpp except that the hpp includes Ode.hpp?

Comment: Woops! Will fix that.

Comment: Thank you, truth is, when defining a namespace you enclose everything inside, using namespace is for when you are accessing the methods, objects, variables already defined. Of course the are ways to circumvent this. I'm just saying that this is the usual way we find these implementations in the wild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cpp enclose your implementation in the namespace aos just like you did in the hpp.

```
namespace aos
{
std::vector< double > * euler(
    std::vector< double > * (*f)(std::vector< double > *, Uint32, Uint32),
    std::vector< double > * x, Uint32 dt, Uint32 t)
{ 
    std::cout << "aos::euler" << std::endl;
    return f(x, dt, t);
}

Integrator::Integrator(){}

std::vector< double > * Integrator::integrate(
    std::vector< double > * (*f)(std::vector< double > *, Uint32, Uint32),
    std::vector< double > * x, Uint32 dt, Uint32 t)
{
    std::cout << "Integrator::integrate" << std::endl;
    return this->integrator(f, x, dt, t);
}
}
```

And you can use the `using namespace aos` in the main.cpp

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I made the incorrect assumption that `using namespace aos;` and `namespace aos{...}` were the same. Except the first one would cover and entire block.

Comment: That's ok, namespaces were really useful for me for hacking a struct with over 40 nested structs with inner nested structs inside. Thanks to them I could decouple everything while maintaining the same names, plus the original legacy implementation was still compatible. They are really useful beyond library enclosing.

Comment: @MrMcKizzle: My advice: *don't code with using directives* (i.e. avoid `using namespace`)